# Cannot interactive rebase: file delted, "Successfully rebased"...?

Tags: git

I am trying to rebase interactively, but when I run `git rebase -i HEAD~6`, the file for the interactive rebase opens and is deleted by git at once. I get the message

> Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feat/pipe/rpc.

and that's it - I can rebase. What is happening?

PS: A similar issue is described in https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/3537, but I am not aware that I would be using any extension.

Comment: Git is not guilty. On `git rebase -i` it prepares the file that contains the rebase plan and opens it using the configured editor (or the default editor on the system if no editor is set in the Git config). Some programs do not allow running more than one instance of them. When a second instance is started it passes the arguments to the first instance (in the best case) and exits. Git (or any other program that started the editor) cannot know when this happens. All it knows is that the editor exited and this means the plan was saved and it can continue. Use a different editor for Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was an issue with my editor (kate). It was already opened with some files. After I completely closed it, I was able to rebase as usual.